# Problema com Composer - PSR-4

Tags: composer, php-autoload, php

Estou estudando Composer e suas formas de autoload (classmap, file, psr-0, psr-4), porém em meu exemplo está aparecendo com o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Library\Exemplo' not found in/var/www/html/CursoPHP/composer/index.php on line 5
```

Minha estrutura de pasta do exemplo é essa:

```
/ comp 
   |-- /src 
     |-- /Library 
           |-- exemplo.php
   |-- /vendor 
   |-- index.php
```

Meu index.php:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$nome = new \Library\Exemplo();
```

Meu composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Library\\": "src/Library"
    }
}
```

Meu exemplo.php:

```
<?php namespace Library;

  class Exemplo
  {
    public function __construct()
    {
      echo 'Classe Exemplo Iniciada';
    }
   }

 ?>
```

Com todos os outros meios de autoload do composer obtive exito, porém não consigo achar o erro do meu exemplo usando o PSR-4.

Comment: Tente trocar `"Library\\": "src/Library"` por `"": "src/"`, além de renomear o arquivo `exemplo.php` para `Exemplo.php` (em maiúsculas).

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti o detalhe todo foi realmente na confusão do nome do arquivo, não sabia que a padrão era "CaseSensitive", que no caso o nome da classe tem que ser exatamente o nome do arquivo.